# Как работает istream& параметр?

Tags: c++, классы, поток-ввода, istream

Помогите разобраться нубу с тем, как работает istream&, конкретно интересует следующая конструкция:

вот есть у меня классы с методами:

```
// класс SimpleAnimalCreator
// constructor
SimpleAnimalCreator::SimpleAnimalCreator(){};

Animal* SimpleAnimalCreator::create(string const & spec, string const & name, int age) {
    if (spec == "Tiger") {
        return new Tiger(name, age);
    };
    if (spec == "Rabbit") {
        return new Rabbit(name, age);
    };
    if (spec == "Sparrow") {
        return new Sparrow(name, age);
    };
    if (spec == "Lizard") {
        return new Lizard(name, age);
    };
    return nullptr;
};
// destructor
SimpleAnimalCreator::~SimpleAnimalCreator(){};


// класс StreamZooCreator
//приватные поля istr и sac;

// constructor
StreamZooCreator::StreamZooCreator(istream & _istr, SimpleAnimalCreator * _sac){

};
// создание зоопарка
Zoo* StreamZooCreator::create(){
    string type;
    string name;
    int age;
    cout << "Ввести животных";
    while (istr)  {
        cin >> type >> name >> age;
        sac -> create(type, name, age);
    }
    return nullptr;
};
// destructor
StreamZooCreator::~StreamZooCreator(){};
```

В задании говорится, что у класса StreamZooCreator должно быть 2 поля типа istream & и SimpleAnimalCreator *, которые инициализируются в конструкторе. Ну и далее метод create() в классе StreamZooCreator должен передавать данные из потока istream  в SimpleAnimalCreator, который создает некоторый объект класса Animal на основе входящих данных.

У меня собственно пара вопросов (первый важный, второй наверно и сам разберусь но на всякий случай):

- как объявлять, инициализировать и что передавать в качестве фактического аргумента для istream& ???
- ну и цикл while потом подправить, чтобы он опирался на входящий поток.

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы header скинули. А то вообще не понятно. Ссылки нужно инициализировать так: допустим в классе есть поле `std::istream & istr`, тогда `StreamZooCreator::StreamZooCreator(std::istream & _istr, SimpleAnimalCreator * _sac) : istr(_istr) {... Тело конструктра... } `

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко спасибо. Этой подсказки достаточно. Задача длинная и запутанная, поэтому не стал скидывать кучу текста. Скинул только то, где было непонятно. Теперь стало ясно, что инициализировать нужно в скобках. А то я там = лепил.

Но теперь непонятно почему поток stream не останавливается, когда я написал одну строку. Вроде должен был цикл прерваться, если у меня всего лишь написано например "Tiger Sher 12".  А он не выходит из цикла

Comment: По поводу while точно не подскажу. Возможно `while (istr.eof());` нужно. В `istr == false `, если будет ошибка чтения. Например вы читаете int, а там буквы написаны. На конец файла он никак не реагирует.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко тут не стал заморачиваться и сделал сразу проверку на тип, и если он не соответствует одному из валидных, то выход:

```
while ((cin >> type) && ((type == "Tiger")||(type == "Rabbit")||(type == "Sparrow")||(type == "Lizard"))) {
        cin >> name >> age;
        // и тд
    }
```

Comment: обычно или в начале пишут длину (быстрее всего, лишние пару в больших файлах погоды не сделают, например так устроена метаинформация в исполняемых файлах), читают до конца файла (end of file - eof, например .ini файлы), или, вдобавок  к этому, испольную открывающиеся и закрывающиеся теги (json, xml). Писать мусор в конец так себе затея, ибо потом никому не объяснишь, что является мусором, а что нет. Быть может кто-то подумает, что qwerty в конце, это такое экзотическое животное.